# All startup applications deleted

Tags: startup-applications

I'm currently using Ubuntu desktop 19.04 lts and I  have accidentally deleted all my start-up apps as I was trying to delete the less necessary which slow down the booting. Now my system is failing to show up the login screen.
What can I do to restore the deleted apps if I'm unable to login in the system? 
I have deleted the start-up applications by session settings gui and and unticked the options in the applications.

Comment: How exactly did you delete all your startup apps? Exactly what else did you do? What is happening when you boot your system? Please be detailed. We cannot see what you see, so please help us to help you.

Comment: I was trying to remove the unnecessary startup apps which slow down the booting and I added up deleting even the most important apps.When I boot the system it only shows me the Ubuntu startup logo which is not loading

Comment: Details - are you running Ubuntu Server?  Ubuntu desktop?  a flavor? What release?  How did you delete the start-up apps?  (terminal? or Session Settings gui and untick options in the Application.Autostart tab? - as we don't know your release it may appear differently to my release that I'm describing). Yes it sounds like you had a unspecified Ubuntu desktop installed (*possibly Gnome, possibly Unity, but could something else*) and it's stuck on a `plymouth` screen but so far you've only been vague and we provide much help with vagueness.

Comment: You could switch to a text terminal (eg. ctrl+alt+f4) and login there, then scan `dmesg` or `journalctl` for clues, but I can't be more specific given i don't know much of what you had or did.  The GUI autostart options I looked at just disabled & enabled autostart services/programs, and don't delete anything)

Comment: Hmmm. What you say you did ("*deleted the start-up applications by session settings gui and and unticked the options in the applications*") cannot prevent the login screen from loading. Either you did something else...or your Ubuntu system had some other coincidental problem. If you don't know how to check your logs, cannot recall additional actions you did, and/or cannot provide additional troubleshooting information, then our best advice will be to re-install Ubuntu. remember to preserve any data you wish to retain before re-installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Will do.Thank you